# Tail of a divergent $p$-series with $p<1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

Consider a divergent $p$-series with $p<1$, for instance $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$. Let $R_{n}=\sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$ be the tail of this series. Obviously $R_n$ diverges as $n \to \infty$, so I was ridiculously trying to find the rate of divergence of the tail. I thought that since the tail of harmonic series behaves very well, we can find the rate $R_n$ as $O(n^{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha>0$. At first I thought that $\alpha$ could be $1/2$, which is clearly incorrect. Is there any way to find the rate of divergence of this sum? Seems my knowledge in approximation is poor. :(

Comment: The tail $R_n$ of the series does not *tend* to infinity; it *is* infinite for each $R_n$.

Comment: Firstly, you probably want $j=1$ as the first sum's lower limit...

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The "tail" 
$$
R_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}
$$
for $\alpha \leq 1$ will not be very interesting to study: it does not "diverge" to infinity, it **is** infinite (exactly because... the series diverges to infinity).

---

However, a more interesting question would be the rate of divergence of the partial sums
$$
S_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}
$$
for $\alpha \leq 1$. Here, a comparison series-integral shows that
$$
S_n(\alpha) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^\alpha}
$$
so that
$$
S_n(\alpha) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \begin{cases}\ln n & \alpha=1\\\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)} & \alpha < 1\end{cases}
$$
For instance, for $\alpha=1/2$, you get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} 2\sqrt{n}\,.$$

Comment: That is the place I misinterpreted the tail and sequence of partial sums. Thanks!

Comment: @Aleph-null You're welcome!

Comment: Now, I understand how valuable Euler constant is.